# GDiskDump or DD to show partition names?

Tags: linux, partition, dd

I have partition names like Data-HD, Yhteinen and W10. I do have lots of other partitions, but I want a little more assurance I am copying a right partition to a correct destination. I am quite errorprone with "names" like /dev/sdbd1 etc.

How do I get partition names to show?

Comment: i'd recommend you to never use `dd` just to obtain partition name

Answer (score 1):

`fdisk -l` or `sfdisk -l` will do the trick and 
`blkid yourdevice` can give you informations about the type, the uid and the filesystem on your device

Comment: with (s)fdisk, you have the partition list and for each partition blkid will give you the information...

Comment: You're right, `lsblk` is far more efficient